# How to wait for QThread eventDispatcher being ready?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

I'm using `QThread`'s event loop to communicate with worker threads.

I noticed that I can't use the thread's event loop just after a `start`.

The following code does not work, as `threadEventDispatcher` appears to be NULL.

```cpp
QThread *thread = new QThread;
thread->start();
auto* threadEventDispatcher = thread->eventDispatcher();
Q_ASSERT(threadEventDispatcher != nullptr);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(threadEventDispatcher, [] { printf("Hello world\n");
```

According to [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qthread.html#setEventDispatcher),

> An event dispatcher is automatically created for the main thread when QCoreApplication is instantiated and on start() for auxiliary threads.

By browsing the QThread source code, I'm under the impression that the `eventDispatcher` is created in the running thread, which may not yet be ready when `start` exits.

I managed to access the `eventDispatcher` by using a *sleep* after the `start`, but I could not find an API that would allow me to properly wait for the thread to actually *run*.

How can I wait for the thread to actually run, and access `eventDispatcher` ?

Comment: Then connect to the started() signal of the QThread and access the eventDispatcher then (for whatever this is needed in the first place though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply connect to `QThread::started()` signal.